# system for storing/retrieving memorable words for login

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, authentication

I'm trying to create a secure system of logging into my website using PHP (5.4) and Mysql (5.1) like some banking systems use.

Briefly;

- User is required to enter a password which is hashed and salted in the MySQL DB
- User is prompted to enter a memorable word (lets say 8 char's long)
- Upon registration, login will have username, password (decrypted from user table) and then be presented with 3 boxes which will chose random letter positions from their memorable word.  If everything is tickety-boo, they can login.

So the username and password bit is easy enough and storing their memorable word as a hash is simple as well.
My question is; what is the most secure way of doing the memorable word storage and confirmation.

In my head it would be a case of writing a function to decrypt the memorable word and then using a random function to ask for 3 characters from their phrase - however, wouldn't this leave the phrase open in the session ?

I could cut corners here but the requirement is to be as secure as possible so I'm just looking for advice on best practice and hopefully someone who's achieved something similar already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to "decrypt" a hashed password.

Comment: Bank use an [HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) so unless you are willing to pay a nice some of money what you are doing is nothing like what banks are doing.

Comment: Thought as much to be honest - a fellow coder of mine has something which kind of works - basically stores their word and encrypts each letter in a separate row in a table - then chooses 3 random rows associated with that user and verifies the letter.  It works but I'm a DBA by trade and it just seems a little inefficient to store - was kind of hoping for an alternative.

Comment: My thoughts on this was to keep password encrypted with salt but to leave the word unencrypted ... it's not as secure in my eyes but can anyone see this as a problem?  In essence we're after 2 or 3 factor authentication, on the cheap (i.e. free) :-)